# Get rid of annoying completion in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Whenever I type `implicit` in IntelliJ, IntelliJ completes it to `implicitly`, which is totally not what I wanted. I haven't found a way to disable this yet. Anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This thread](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5299975#5299975) mentions the same bug, but adds:

> Arr well, nevermind. I found the settings for:
>   "**`Preselect the first suggestion" --> "Never"`** now.
>   Should have checked the prefs first.

This isn't a good solution, only a temporary workaround, and the last message (Apr 12, 2011) mentions:

> That's fixed now, check the next nightly.

So did you check with a recent version of IntelliJ? (10 or just released 10.5)

Comment: I tried 10.5 yesterday, but didn't check for this. Will try again later. Thanks.

Comment: I run into it in ActionScript on occasion too which makes me wonder whether there's not a platform issue. I didn't notice the workaround in Track thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should post this either [directly as a bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/SCL) or to the Idea [Scala plugin forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/idea/scala?view=discussions).

Unfortunately this is not an answer to the question. But I hope by following my advice, the problem will disappear sooner or later.